# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 443) from /10.0.2.15 (port 43794) after 2000ms

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write a program in the android studio. I'm shooting the database with the webservice rest api. But I get this error, I couldn't log in.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvJWP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce8bT.png)

Comment: Is your webservice really listing on an SSL port?  What if you try `http://10.0.2.2/` instead of `https`?

Comment: Was the JavaScript tag a mistake?

Comment: I get this error when I do http  java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to 10.0.2.2 not permitted by network security policy

Comment: Google for clear text traffic.

Comment: yes but I tried all the solutions on the internet about it but I could not get a result.

Comment: I wrote this in the manifest android: networkSecurityConfig = I wrote the code "@ xml / network_security_config" if it is xml, it still gives the same error I wrote this in xm <network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted = "true">
        <domain includeSubdomains = "true"> 192.168.1.100 </domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains = "true"> http://example1.com </domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains = "true"> example1.com </domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config> but no result

Answer (score 2):

on your okhttp client builder the connection timeout is 3 second, also make sure you are adding internet permission to the manifest file,

- cleartextTrafficPermitted=false on manifest file.
- if you are running the web service from the local servers like wamp or xxamp make sure to add all configurations required check [this](http://androidcss.com/android/test-android-app-php-localhost-wamp/) link

Comment: Hello, I did the part you showed false. I am using Xammp and I did everything necessary as far as I know but still java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to 10.0.2.2 not permitted by network security policy gives this error.

Comment: the best solution to upload the webservice to the server, just buy a cheap one, on the local server you will find a lot of issues like caching connection ...etc